# Conditional join based on multiple attributes , optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following query :

```
SELECT 
  *
 FROM Employees E
 JOIN States S ON E.idEmployee = S.idEmployee
 LEFT JOIN Data1 D1 ON S.data1 = D1.data1
 LEFT JOIN Data2 D2 ON S.data2 = D2.data2
 LEFT JOIN Data3 D3 ON S.data3 = D3.data3

 WHERE (S.idStateType = 1 and D1.attribute1 = value)
    OR (S.idStateType = 2 and D2.attribute2 = value and D2.attribute3 = value)
    OR (S.idStateType = 3 and (D1.attribute1 = value or D3.attribute3 = value))
```

The second join (table Data2) is valid only if the S.idStateType = 2, which will become unecessary if the idStateType is <> 2 .

If I'm changing the join condition to depend on the idStateType , would it matter ( from optimziation point of view but also design view) ?

It would become :

```
LEFT JOIN data2 DT ON S.idStateType = 2 AND S.data2 = D2.data2
```

Comment: I.e move those conditions to the `ON` clauses instead.

Comment: D1.attribute1 = value in the where changes that left join to a regular join

Comment: @jarlh could you elaborate please?

Comment: as per @Frisbee you will need to change the WHERE conditions to (D1.attribute1 is null or D1.attribute1 = value) OR etc.

Comment: @SteveFord - Why should I be doing that ? Shouldn't be (d1.attribute is not null and d1.attribute = value ) ?

Comment: Put your where in your on clause, and only select the fields you need instead of select * (scan in the place of seek operator), it can also be good to nest your joins select from (select from) keeping your datasets as small as possible.

Comment: @Leon if you do as you suggest you are turning your LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part your query here should be fine. SQL is an interpreted language so it does not necessarily run in the order you write it but rather it runs it what it believes to be the most efficient order based on what it believes the results to look like. If you want to truly test your results toggle "Include Actual Execution Plan" in the "SQL Editor" bar in SSMS and run the query a couple different ways to see what the most efficient way is.

You could rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT 
 *
 FROM Employees E
 JOIN States S ON E.idEmployee = S.idEmployee
 LEFT JOIN Data1 D1 ON S.data1 = D1.data1 AND S.idStateType = 1
  AND D1.attribute1 = value
 LEFT JOIN Data2 D2 ON S.data2 = D2.data2 AND S.idStateType = 2
  and D2.attribute2 = value and D2.attribute3 = value
 LEFT JOIN Data3 D3 ON S.data3 = D3.data3 AND S.idStateType = 3
  and (D1.attribute1 = value or D3.attribute3 = value)
```

Doing this could potentially speed up the query, however the actually interpreter will have the final say based on the table structures and indexing. Using the execution plan can help to determine how the interpreter is running this query and can assist in finding the best way to optimize.

Comment: This would not limit S.idStateType to (1,2,3)